# If $\mathrm A = \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 25\}$ and $\mathrm B = \{ (x,y): x^2 + 9y^2 = 144 \}$, Find $ n( \text A \; \cap \; \text B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$ if \mathrm A = \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 25\}$$
$$ and \; \mathrm B = \{ (x,y): x^2 + 9y^2 = 144 \}$$
$$ \text Find \; n( \text A \; \cap \; \text B)$$

Answer Given in Textbook = 4.

Given, x and y are 2 variables, which are real numbers.

Problem - **We have only studied simple algebra in one and two variables (equations using 2 variables using substitution, cancellation, cross-multiplication method), Hyperbola and Graph related stuff are not introduced**.

In Sets - **Basic Operations i.e. Union, Intersection, Belongs to, subsets, subtraction and complimentary.**

So, is there any way to solve this problem without Using Complex Graphs and Hyperbola and Parabola?

So, there are two ways I've tried.

**First** - **Manually using Hit and Trial Method**, which gets (3, 4), (4, 3), (-3, 4) and (4, -3) which satisfies the first equation in set A, but none of those satisfies the value for the Second equation for the set B, so it's clear that there are no integers which are part of the four answers.

Second - $$ x^2 + y^2 = 25 
\implies x^2 = 25 - y^2 $$
Now, **using this value of $ x^2 $ in the second equation to get value of $ y = 4$
but that doesn't seems to work.**

I'm not sure if there's any other way.
Please keep the solution simple.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$x^2=25-y^2$$

then

$$x^2+9y^2=144\to 25-y^2+9y^2=144\to y^2=\frac{119}{8}\to y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{119}{8}}$$

can you solve for $x$ and find $4$ solutions?

Comment: that doesn't works :(

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha: why not?

Comment: Yes, it does. All four solutions have $y$ being one of these two numbers. *You* still have to find $x$, though.

Comment: can you please complete that?

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha: you can complete by yourself. Try a little bit.

Comment: I tried that but that doesn't works for me

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha: you just have to plug the value of $y$ at the first equation and find those two values of $x$. After that take all $4$ combination of the pair $(x,y)$

Comment: I can't figure how you got four solutions... :( I get $ + \sqrt { \frac{119}{8}} and - \sqrt{ \frac{119}{8}}$

Comment: What values of $x$ did you find?

Comment: Oh okay 2 values of x and 2 values of y?

Comment: Almost! With $2$ values of $x$ and $2$ values of $y$ how many pairs $(x,y)$ can you get?

Comment: How do you solve these questions that quick?!